# How to return a value only when "ok" is clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, prompt

I have created a custimazibale prompt

```
public static class Prompt
{
    public static string ShowDialog(int columnnumber, string columnname)
    {
        Form prompt = new Form();
        prompt.Width = 500;
        prompt.Height = 150;
        prompt.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
        prompt.Text = columnname;
        prompt.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        Label textLabel = new Label() { Left = 50, Top = 20 };
        ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox() { Left = 50, Top = 50, Width = 400 };
        comboBox.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "a","b","c" });
        comboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        comboBox.SelectedItem = columnname;
        Button confirmation = new Button() { Text = "Ok", Left = 350, Width = 100, Top = 80 };
        confirmation.Click += (sender, e) => { prompt.Close(); };
        textLabel.Text = "Colonne " + (columnnumber + 1).ToString() + " : " + columnname;
        prompt.Controls.Add(comboBox);
        prompt.Controls.Add(confirmation);
        prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel);
        prompt.AcceptButton = confirmation;
        prompt.ShowDialog();
        prompt.AcceptButton = confirmation;

        return comboBox.Text;
    }
}
```

then I call it in my main form when a header is clicked

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
     dt.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].ColumnName = Prompt.ShowDialog(e.ColumnIndex, dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name);
}
```

The problem is my text change even if the button close is clicked.
But I want it to change only when the user click the button "OK".

Answer (score 6):

You could evaluate the [`DialogResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and return `null` if it is not `OK`:

```
public static class Prompt
{
    public static string ShowDialog(int columnnumber, string columnname)
    {
        using (Form prompt = new Form())
        {
            // other code
            return prompt.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK ? comboBox.Text : null;
        }
    }
}
```

and then in your other method:

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var result = Prompt.ShowDialog(e.ColumnIndex, 
                                   dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name);
    if (result != null)
        dt.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].ColumnName = result;
}
```

And inside your `prompt` you should set the `DialogResult` accordingly:

```
confirmation.Click += (sender, e) =>
    {
        prompt.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        prompt.Close();
    };
```

*HINT:* Instead of `result != null` you could also use `!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result)` to only update the column name if something was entered.

Comment: This is probably better than just setting a local variable as per my answer.

Comment: The form will just get hidden once the DialogResult is set, but if the form  is inside of an using it will get disposed after you are done with processing the DialogResult if I`m not mistaken.

Comment: @MeAndSomeRandoms: True, as long as you use `ShowDialog`. Using `Show` (not the case here) it would only set the property. Also the form is only hidden and `Close` is NOT automatically called in that case, hence the "manual call" if e.g. someone is listening for the closing event...

Comment: I used this solution at last, it's better.
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I would go for something like this:

```
using(Form prompt = new Form())
{
    //Initialize the components of your form

    DialogResult result = prompt.ShowDialog();
    if(result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
       //return whatever it is you want to return
    }
}
```

Inside your form you can set the DialogResult via `prompt.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK` and some more options (DialogResult.Cancel, DialogResult.Retry etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can set a bool when it is confirmed, and use that to return null if it wasn't confirmed, like this:

```
public static string ShowDialog(int columnnumber, string columnname)
{
    Form prompt = new Form();
    prompt.Width = 500;
    prompt.Height = 150;
    prompt.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
    prompt.Text = columnname;
    prompt.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    Label textLabel = new Label()
    {
        Left = 50,
        Top = 20
    };
    ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox()
    {
        Left = 50,
        Top = 50,
        Width = 400
    };
    comboBox.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "a", "b", "c" });
    comboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
    comboBox.SelectedItem = columnname;
    Button confirmation = new Button()
    {
        Text = "Ok",
        Left = 350,
        Width = 100,
        Top = 80
    };

    bool confirmed = false;

    confirmation.Click += (sender, e) =>
    {
        prompt.Close();
        confirmed = true;
    };
    textLabel.Text = "Colonne " + (columnnumber + 1).ToString() + " : " + columnname;
    prompt.Controls.Add(comboBox);
    prompt.Controls.Add(confirmation);
    prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel);
    prompt.AcceptButton = confirmation;
    prompt.ShowDialog();
    prompt.AcceptButton = confirmation;

    return confirmed ? comboBox.Text : null;
}
```

Your calling code will need to check the return value for null, and only do something if the returned value is not null.